# Adding and removing roles based on variables

Tags: mysql, cron, discord.js

I've written about 95% of the code I need to make this work, just need to finish it up so that the embed message that gets sent, shows the list of people whose roles were adjusted correctly. Can someone point me in the right direction to get the members sorted and the posted on in the embed correctly?

Here is the code:

```js
cron.schedule('00 12 * * *', function () {
    con.query(`SELECT * FROM users WHERE member = 'Yes' AND user_registered < DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 14 DAY)`, (err, rows) => {
        if (err) throw err

        rows.slice().forEach(row => {
            const discord = row.discord
            const member = bot.users.cache.get(discord)
            const rank = row.rank
            const messages = row.messages
            const registered = row.user_registered
            const days = Math.round((Date.now() / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24) - (registered / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24))

            if (days >= 14 && messages >= 150 && rank === 'Recruit') {
                member.roles.remove(member.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Recruit'))
                member.roles.add(member.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Noble'))
            } else if (days >= 30 && messages >= 750 && rank === 'Noble') {
                member.roles.remove(member.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Noble'))
                member.roles.add(member.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Hero'))
            } else if (days >= 90 && messages >= 1500 && rank === 'Hero') {
                member.roles.remove(member.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Hero'))
                member.roles.add(member.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Fabled'))
            } else if (days >= 180 && messages >= 3000 && rank === 'Fabled') {
                member.roles.remove(member.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Fabled'))
                member.roles.add(member.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Mythic'))
            } else if (days >= 365 && messages >= 6000 && rank === 'Mythic') {
                member.roles.remove(member.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Mythic'))
                member.roles.add(member.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Legend'))
            }

            const noble = a //This needs to be set up
            const hero = b //This needs to be set up
            const fabled = c //This needs to be set up
            const mythic = d //This needs to be set up
            const legend = e //This needs to be set up

            const promotionEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setColor('#ff6600')
                .setTitle('Promotions')
                .setDescription(`The following members have been promoted:`)
                .addFields({
                    name: 'Noble',
                    value: `${noble.join('\n')}` || 'None', //This needs to be set up
                    inline: true
                }, {
                    name: 'Hero',
                    value: `${hero.join('\n')}` || 'None', //This needs to be set up
                    inline: true
                }, {
                    name: 'Fabled',
                    value: `${fabled.join('\n')}` || 'None', //This needs to be set up
                    inline: true
                }, {
                    name: 'Mythic',
                    value: `${mythic.join('\n')}` || 'None', //This needs to be set up
                    inline: true
                }, {
                    name: 'Legend',
                    value: `${legend.join('\n')}` || 'None', //This needs to be set up
                    inline: true
                })

            genchat.send(promotionEmbed)
        })
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Skulaurun got me from 95% to 99%, just had to tweak how member was defined and add some more sql to update the database, but here is the finished working code.

This code assigns members roles based on server activity (messages sent) and time (how long they have been registered to the server) information that is stored in a mysql database.

```js
cron.schedule('51 10 * * *', function () {
    con.query(`SELECT * FROM users WHERE member = 'Yes' AND user_registered < DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 14 DAY)`, (err, rows) => {
        if (err) throw err

        const genchat = bot.channels.cache.get('785187526477742141');

        let noble = []
        let hero = []
        let fabled = []
        let mythic = []
        let legend = []

        rows.slice().forEach(row => {
            const guild = bot.guilds.cache.get('779892144026288179')
            const discord = row.discord
            const member = guild.members.cache.get(discord)
            const rank = row.rank
            const messages = row.messages
            const registered = row.user_registered
            const days = Math.round((Date.now() / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24) - (registered / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24))

            if (days >= 14 && messages >= 150 && rank === 'Recruit') {
                member.roles.remove(guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Recruit'))
                member.roles.add(guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Noble'))

                noble.push(member)

                con.query(`UPDATE users SET rank = 'Noble' WHERE discord = '${member.user.id}'`, (err) => {
                    if (err) throw err
                })
            } else if (days >= 30 && messages >= 750 && rank === 'Noble') {
                member.roles.remove(guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Noble'))
                member.roles.add(guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Hero'))

                hero.push(member)

                con.query(`UPDATE users SET rank = 'Hero' WHERE discord = '${member.user.id}'`, (err) => {
                    if (err) throw err
                })
            } else if (days >= 90 && messages >= 1500 && rank === 'Hero') {
                member.roles.remove(guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Hero'))
                member.roles.add(guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Fabled'))

                fabled.push(member)

                con.query(`UPDATE users SET rank = 'Fabled' WHERE discord = '${member.user.id}'`, (err) => {
                    if (err) throw err
                })
            } else if (days >= 180 && messages >= 3000 && rank === 'Fabled') {
                member.roles.remove(guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Fabled'))
                member.roles.add(guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Mythic'))

                mythic.push(member)

                con.query(`UPDATE users SET rank = 'Mythic' WHERE discord = '${member.user.id}'`, (err) => {
                    if (err) throw err
                })
            } else if (days >= 365 && messages >= 6000 && rank === 'Mythic') {
                member.roles.remove(guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Mythic'))
                member.roles.add(guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Legend'))
                
                legend.push(member)

                con.query(`UPDATE users SET rank = 'Legend' WHERE discord = '${member.user.id}'`, (err) => {
                    if (err) throw err
                })
            }
        })

        const promotionEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#ff6600')
            .setTitle('Promotions')
            .setDescription(`The following members have been promoted:`)
            .addFields({
                name: 'Noble',
                value: `${noble.join('\n')}` || 'None',
                inline: true
            }, {
                name: 'Hero',
                value: `${hero.join('\n')}` || 'None',
                inline: true
            }, {
                name: 'Fabled',
                value: `${fabled.join('\n')}` || 'None',
                inline: true
            }, {
                name: 'Mythic',
                value: `${mythic.join('\n')}` || 'None',
                inline: true
            }, {
                name: 'Legend',
                value: `${legend.join('\n')}` || 'None',
                inline: true
            })
        genchat.send(promotionEmbed)

    })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```js
const noble = member.guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.roles.cache.find(role => role.name == "Noble")).array();
const hero =  member.guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.roles.cache.find(role => role.name == "Hero")).array();
const fabled = member.guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.roles.cache.find(role => role.name == "Fabled")).array();
const mythic = member.guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.roles.cache.find(role => role.name == "Mythic")).array();
const legend = member.guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.roles.cache.find(role => role.name == "Legend")).array();
```

You filter the guild members and leave the ones that have the roles.

EDIT:

```js
cron.schedule('00 12 * * *', function () {
    con.query(`SELECT * FROM users WHERE member = 'Yes' AND user_registered < DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 14 DAY)`, (err, rows) => {
        if (err) throw err

        let noble = []
        let hero = []
        let fabled = []
        let mythic = []
        let legend = []

        rows.slice().forEach(row => {
            const discord = row.discord
            const member = bot.users.cache.get(discord)
            const rank = row.rank
            const messages = row.messages
            const registered = row.user_registered
            const days = Math.round((Date.now() / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24) - (registered / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24))

            if (days >= 14 && messages >= 150 && rank === 'Recruit') {
                member.roles.remove(member.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Recruit'))
                member.roles.add(member.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Noble'))
                noble.push(member)
            } else if (days >= 30 && messages >= 750 && rank === 'Noble') {
                member.roles.remove(member.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Noble'))
                member.roles.add(member.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Hero'))
                hero.push(member)
            } else if (days >= 90 && messages >= 1500 && rank === 'Hero') {
                member.roles.remove(member.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Hero'))
                member.roles.add(member.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Fabled'))
                fabled.push(member)
            } else if (days >= 180 && messages >= 3000 && rank === 'Fabled') {
                member.roles.remove(member.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Fabled'))
                member.roles.add(member.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Mythic'))
                mythic.push(member)
            } else if (days >= 365 && messages >= 6000 && rank === 'Mythic') {
                member.roles.remove(member.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Mythic'))
                member.roles.add(member.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Legend'))
                legend.push(member)
            }
        })

        const promotionEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#ff6600')
            .setTitle('Promotions')
            .setDescription(`The following members have been promoted:`)
            .addFields({
                name: 'Noble',
                value: `${noble.join('\n')}` || 'None', //This needs to be set up
                inline: true
            }, {
                name: 'Hero',
                value: `${hero.join('\n')}` || 'None', //This needs to be set up
                inline: true
            }, {
                name: 'Fabled',
                value: `${fabled.join('\n')}` || 'None', //This needs to be set up
                inline: true
            }, {
                name: 'Mythic',
                value: `${mythic.join('\n')}` || 'None', //This needs to be set up
                inline: true
            }, {
                name: 'Legend',
                value: `${legend.join('\n')}` || 'None', //This needs to be set up
                inline: true
            })
        genchat.send(promotionEmbed)

    })
})
```

If I understand correctly, each row is one discord user. You need to accumulate the changes to the users outside the foreach. And send the message after the for loop ended.

Haven't tested anything, hope it helps.

Comment: Wouldn't that then pull up all members of that role rather than the ones whose roles were changed?

Comment: I have updated my answer. That should send only the ones with adjusted roles.